# is it possible to create an elif loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Hi is it possible to create a loop for the following?

Any ideas would help.

```
if sun_angle < -18:
    shade = 399
elif sun_angle < -17.9:
    shade = 396
elif sun_angle < -17.8:
    shade = 393
elif sun_angle < -17.7:
    shade = 390
elif sun_angle < -17.6:
    shade = 387
elif sun_angle < -17.5:
    shade = 384
elif sun_angle < -17.4:
    shade = 381
elif sun_angle < -17.3:
    shade = 378
elif sun_angle < -17.2:
    shade = 375
elif sun_angle < -17.1:
    shade = 372
elif sun_angle < -16.9:
    shade = 369
elif sun_angle < -16.8:
    shade = 366
elif sun_angle < -16.7:
    shade = 363
elif sun_angle < -16.6:
    shade = 360
elif sun_angle < -16.5:
    shade = 357
elif sun_angle < -16.4:
    shade = 354
elif sun_angle < -16.3:
    shade = 351
elif sun_angle < -16.2:
    shade = 348
elif sun_angle < -16.1:
    shade = 345
elif sun_angle < -16.0:
    shade = 342
elif sun_angle < -15.9:
    shade = 339
elif sun_angle < -15.8:
    shade = 336
elif sun_angle < -15.7:
    shade = 333
elif sun_angle < -15.6:
    shade = 330
elif sun_angle < -15.5:
    shade = 327
elif sun_angle < -15.4:
    shade = 324
elif sun_angle < -15.3:
    shade = 321
elif sun_angle < -15.2:
    shade = 318
elif sun_angle < -15.1:
    shade = 315
elif sun_angle < -15.0:
    shade = 312
else:
    shade = '0'
```

Comment: I guess it's clear that changes in statements are linear. Please reduce amount of code to valuable minimum so StackOverflow will allow you to use code formatting for all your code. Try to display only range from 18 to 17 degrees

Answer (score 1):

As your conditions and corresponding values has a linear pattern, you can do that with a simple calculation. (Thanks to @PeterCurran for mentioning unnecessarily use of `Decimal` module which I did before)

I've put comment inside the code for clarification:

```
start_number = -18.0
start_value = 399
stop_number = -15.0
step = 0.1


def get_number(x):
    # This is your else part
    if x > stop_number:
        return '0'

    # We want to know how many "0.1" should be subtracted from
    # your start_number which is 399 and then multiply it by 3.
    n = (abs(start_number - x) / step)
    return int(start_value - (3 * n))


print(get_number(-17.8))
print(get_number(25))
```

output :

```
393
0
```

btw, In OP you missed the condition `elif sun_angle < -17.0:` so next values are incorrect.

Comment: @zaspa Happy to help, You can accept an answer which you found most useful by pressing that check mark button.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary - nice answer. I think for this example using the `Decimal` module isn't essential and it would be perfectly reasonable to use floats. The limitation of float precision isn't really an issue for this simple division?

Comment: @PeterCurran Actually it is. Pass `-17.8` value which should gives `393` as a result. By converting all Decimals to `float`, it gives `396.0`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, to use only floats you would also need to use the "simple division" operator `/` rather than the "floor division" `//`.  Doing this gives the expected output. I am not saying using the `Decimal` module is incorrect only that it is not essential.

Comment: @PeterCurran My bad, You're right. I've updated the answer.